# Forcing a column to require sorting in Ant Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

So currently I have a table with sorting enabled on one of the columns, the column being createdAt. I want the table to always be sorted but currently how its working is that the column will toggle between DESC, to none, to ASC. This is causing me some headache since for the end user experience the table should always be sorted in some direction, and for future tables with multiple sorting columns I also want sorting to be required. I can't find any properties on the table or column to support this type of behavior so for a temporary work around I'm just checking on the back-end if its receiving the sorting params and if it isn't it just defaults to DESC on id.

Columns are defined in an array of objects and then used as a property on the ant design table. below is my date created column object

```
{
  title: 'Date Created',
  dataIndex: 'createdAt',
  key: 'createdAt',
  width: '17%',
  sorter: (a, b) =>
    (new Date(a.createdAt).getTime() - new Date(b.createdAt).getTime()) /
    (1000 * 3600 * 24),
  defaultSortOrder: 'descend',
  ...getColumnSearchProps('createdAt'),
  render: createdAt => {
    return (
      <span>
        {new Date(createdAt).getMonth()}/{new Date(createdAt).getDate()}/
        {new Date(createdAt).getFullYear()}
      </span>
    );
  }
},
```

and the ant design table component

```
<Table
    columns={columns}
    rowKey={record => record.id}
    dataSource={data}
    pagination={pagination}
    loading={loading}
    onChange={handleTableChange}
  />
```

**Update:**
Below is a link to a code sandbox from the ant design website showcasing how sorting on tables works. My issue has to do with the ant design framework and not my code. If you sort the columns after the column is already ascending it disables the sort. I want my table to always have sorting on, all I need to do is remove the ability to disable the sort. Just looking for ideas. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/y4pxx

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You should definitely provide some code, sort feature in a table is not standard html.

Comment: @Apolo just updated, this is in reference to the Ant Design react UI framework and is definitely not using standard html. Hope that helps

Comment: Everything look okay in the code above, could you post a code sandbox and show what the issue is? My best guess right now would be that the sorter that you wrote now isn't working as you expect it to.

Comment: @ShivamGupta Not an issue with the code at all, has to do with the framework. I updated the question above to have a link to a code sandbox. Just play around with sorting and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Ah now I understand what you mean. You want to disable the default sort (no sort option for the table) right?

Comment: @ShivamGupta Close, the default sort is fine because it defaults to sorting by age descending. But if you try to change the sort direction to ascending it disables the sort. I want to make it so sorting is required and you can't disable the sort.

Comment: Let me look a bit more into it, right now I don't see any way of doing this. Like you said, its part of the library functionality. i'd recommend dropping an issue on their github and seeing if they respond with any solution.

Comment: Maybe look at (https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-reset-filter) and use the sortedInfo object as used in the example and keep it set to descend onClick.

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: I cannot believe ANTD added a hidden 3rd sort order option of  "none", it's not even in their API docs. Every 3rd click appears to be "none" which i also do not understand.  Any fix on this?

Answer (score 4):

I have just faced with the same issue, and there is my solution:

At the `columns` define the sort directions like this:

```
sortDirections: ['ascend', 'descend', 'ascend']
```

Instead of this:

```
sortDirections: ['descend', 'ascend']
```

Comment: Hell man! Thank you. Developers say they are not going to add this feature but looks like even they do not aware of this workaround

Comment: Thanks a ton man! I spent almost half a day looking for this configuration in their documentation. You saved my night. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can just render the column filter as you want, there is [an official example](https://codesandbox.io/s/y4pxx) for it.

Use `filterDropdown` with `filterIcon` to render a custom sorter as you like,
both properties accepts `ReactNode` as expected.

> `filterDropdown` Customized filter overlay `React.ReactNode | (props: FilterDropdownProps) => React.ReactNode`

---

> `filterIcon`
>   Customized filter icon `ReactNode|(filtered: boolean) => ReactNode`

Reference:
 - [`Column` component](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column).